# No WiFi in Debian after suspending or closing the lid

Tags: debian, wifi, suspend, laptop, internet

I know that this question is posted a few times already, but I tried many of the solutions there and they didn't work.

If I start my Laptop (restart or fresh boot after being turned off) the WiFi works most of the time and I can connect to it without a problem. *Not always though*

If I'm connected and close the lid or press the power button so that the laptop goes into suspend mode, after I open it up again, I can't connect to the internet. The available networks are shown, but all of them only have a 10% strength and nothing happens when I try to connect to them.

If I deactivate and activate WiFi again (either by the switch in network-manager or by the F-Key on the keyboard), it shows WiFi as "not connected".

I tried to restart `network-manager` after the suspension, but that didn't fix the problem.

I know that this is not a lot of debugging information, but I'm not knowledgeable enough of Linux to be able to give you a more relevant one. But I'm happy to provide it, if you tell me what exactly.

EDIT: After thinking about the problem a little bit more I also remembered the following: If I let the Laptop suspend by going idle and waiting for the 5 minutes it requires, I sometimes have WiFi after booting up again. It also happened recently, that I was playing in offline mode (because I had no WiFi) and after quite some time I could connect to the Internet again (I think about an hour, but I'm not exactly sure). I have seen this phenomenon very rarely and it only happened on a few occasions.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having trouble for same.  I think the problem lies in new driver installation, it adds the suspend_modules line in `/etc/pm/config.d/unload_modules` file but comment the same line whereas it should comment old one.  I edited manually and it worked.  Hope it will help yours as well.

```
$ cat /etc/pm/config.d/unload_modules
SUSPEND_MODULES="$SUSPEND_MODULES cfg80211 mac80211"
#SUSPEND_MODULES="$SUSPEND_MODULES iwldvm iwlwifi mac80211"
```

Edit the file as follow using editor of your choice.  Yours will be different but the idea is comment the first line and uncomment the second

```
#SUSPEND_MODULES="$SUSPEND_MODULES cfg80211 mac80211"
SUSPEND_MODULES="$SUSPEND_MODULES iwldvm iwlwifi mac80211"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the WiFi running by disabling all type of suspension.

---

For systems which should never attempt any type of suspension, these targets can be disabled at the systemd level with the following:

```bash
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

To re-enable hibernate and suspend use the following command:

```bash
sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

Reference: https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend#Disable_suspend_and_hibernation